# how to make remote debug `/gradlew jettyRun` in idea

Tags: gradlew

I set an environment variable `export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"`, and add a remote debug in idea>Run>edit configurations .

But it doesn't works when I run `./gradlew jettyRun`.

The following is the output.

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
enter code here Error listing versions of org.codehaus.groovy:groovy using class org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenVersionLister$1. Will attempt an alternate way to list versions. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
```